# Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONObject] and content type [application/json]

Tags: android, post, resttemplate

I'm digging myself in trying to send a POST request with a JSON payload to a remote server.

This GET curl command works fine:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" --user aaa@aaa.com:aaa "http://www.aaa.com:8080/aaa-project-rest/api/users/1" -i
```

And this POST one works fine too:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://www.aaa.com:8080/aaa-project-rest/api/users/login" -X POST -d "{ \"email\" : \"aaa@aaa.com\", \"password\" : \"aaa\" }" -i
```

And so I'm trying to mimic it in my Android app.

The app works fine on the first GET request but gives a 400 Bad Request on the second POST one.

Here is the code that works for the GET request:

```
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("aaa@aaa.com" + ":" + "aaa");
  User user = null;
  ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://" + REST_HOST + ":8080/aaa-project-rest/api/users/" + 1L, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders), User.class);
```

Here is the source code for the POST request:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
User user = null;
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
JSONObject jsonCredentials = new JSONObject();
jsonCredentials.put("email", REST_LOGIN);
jsonCredentials.put("password", REST_PASSWORD);
ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://" + REST_HOST + ":" + REST_PORT + "/" + REST_APP + "/api/users/login",
        HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<Object>(jsonCredentials, httpHeaders), User.class);
```

But it gives the message:

```
Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONObject] and content type [application/json]
```

Here is the Spring REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<UserResource> login(@Valid @RequestBody CredentialsResource credentialsResource, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    User user = credentialsService.checkPassword(credentialsResource);
    userService.clearReadablePassword(user);
    if (user == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserResource>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        tokenAuthenticationService.addTokenToResponseHeader(responseHeaders, credentialsResource.getEmail());
        responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.USERS + RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        UserResource createdUserResource = userResourceAssembler.toResource(user);
        ResponseEntity<UserResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<UserResource>(createdUserResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<UserResource> findById(@PathVariable Long id, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserResource>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        UserResource userResource = userResourceAssembler.toResource(user);
        responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.USERS + RESTConstants.SLASH + "{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        ResponseEntity<UserResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<UserResource>(userResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

The CredentialsResource class code:

```
public class CredentialsResource extends ResourceSupport {

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    public CredentialsResource() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show definition of the REST Controller on the server?

Comment: @SergeyYamshchikov I added the controller. Also I notice now the response is a 401 Unauthorized

Comment: The curl request is users/1 but the android is users/login

Comment: For the unauthorized part, you're not sending the user/pass on the headers

Comment: @JavierMollá Spot on. I just also noticed it. I changed the example curl request to match it to the application request.

Comment: @JavierMollá Do you see anything wrong in the ways I try passing the header ?

Comment: Sorry guys. There was a typo I introduced in the application request which triggered the 401. Now that it is corrected the response is a beautiful 200.

Comment: I was messing up my question with two different requests. I cleaned up the whole test and it hopefully now makes sense to the new reader.

Comment: What I undestand from your requests is that /users/1 works with basic authentication but /users/login does not (You're not passing credentials in the same way). Is it right?

Comment: @JavierMollá Exactly. The login url request passes a json object with the credentials, and not in the headers. The demo curl shows this to work.

Comment: Can you post CredentialsResource class code?

Comment: I posted the CredentialsResource class code.

Comment: I wonder why the app request makes the server look up for a single string constructor, when the example curl one does not.

Comment: At first, this was a REST Angular app and I'm tried adding an Android client to it. I first do a login request and then the server creates a JWT JSON Web Token which is used in subsequent requests.
You reckon I could move this:
tokenAuthenticationService.addTokenToResponseHeader(responseHeaders, credentialsResource.getEmail()); 
out of the login controller
and into the security filter ?
Then I would not need the login controller any longer..
I wonder what is best, when doing a JWT, if it is to use the login controller or a security filter.
Is it a good design to mix Basic auth with JWT ?

Comment: Answer with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56366641/6346531

Answer (score 30):

Quite late to reply, though I've just hitten the same problem and took me some time to solve it. So, I think I'd better share it and keep track of my solution.

Actually, the exception thrown is totally misleading. Turned out the problem is not that the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` didn't know how to marshall my object -which sounded strange, being JSON-, but a configuration of the underlying `ObjectMapper`.

What I did is to **disable** the property `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` like that

```
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jsonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonHttpMessageConverter);
```

and everything started working as expected.

Comment: I encountered the same issue and found it to be because of the absence of getters and setters to the POJO that I was trying to "jsonify". After adding the getters and setters, the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks @VivekSethi, my issue was missing getters and setters too.

Comment: For me was also missing getters, thanks @VivekSethi.

Comment: If I am trying above code with @Bean RestTemplate is sending null values with POST request

Answer (score 9):

I had to do a few things to get this working.

First I had to convert the JSONObject to a string, as in:

```
HttpEntity<String> entityCredentials = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonCredentials.toString(), httpHeaders);
```

The reason being that there is no mapping message converter for the JSONObject class while there is one for the String class.

Second I had to pass a true value to the RestTemplate constructor. Failing to do so, I would get a 400 Bad Request.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
```

The true value tells the rest template to use the default converters. If someone knows why this is so, I'd be happy to know more about.

Third I removed the unneeded Jackson converter:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

With these things done, the request works just fine.

Here is the full code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);    
User user = null;
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
try {
    JSONObject jsonCredentials = new JSONObject();
    jsonCredentials.put("email", REST_LOGIN);
    jsonCredentials.put("password", REST_PASSWORD);
    Log.e(Constants.APP_NAME, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> JSON credentials " + jsonCredentials.toString());
    HttpEntity<String> entityCredentials = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonCredentials.toString(), httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://" + REST_HOST + ":" + REST_PORT + "/" + REST_APP + "/api/users/login",
            HttpMethod.POST, entityCredentials, User.class);
    if (responseEntity != null) {
        user = responseEntity.getBody();
    }
    return user;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(Constants.APP_NAME, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
return null;
```

I suspect there could be a way to explicitly use a Jackson converter and skip the true value in the rest template constructor, but this is just a guess.

Comment: does your User class implement serializable, has public getters and setters and a public empty default constructor?

Because spring boot should than automatically configure & use Jackson and serialize/deserialize your DTO class fine.

Comment: Good question but I left that project years ago and haven't touch native Android coding since.

Comment: maybe you remember ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Exception "no suitable HTTPMessageConverter found" is thrown, if not JSON implementation is present in the class path. Have a look at RestTemplate source code:

```
public RestTemplate() {
    this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    this.messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    this.messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    this.messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());
    this.messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());

    if (romePresent) {
        this.messageConverters.add(new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter());
        this.messageConverters.add(new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    if (jackson2XmlPresent) {
        this.messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
    }
    else if (jaxb2Present) {
        this.messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    if (jackson2Present) {
        this.messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
    else if (gsonPresent) {
        this.messageConverters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

Add a JSON implementation to your class path. E. g.:

```
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know... is too late. But here I am.

I fixed this sending a Java Object instead a JSONObject, something like this:

```
JSONObject jsonCredentials = new JSONObject();
jsonCredentials.put("email", REST_LOGIN);
jsonCredentials.put("password", REST_PASSWORD);

// Generic Object. It might be a DTO.
Object jsonCredentialsObj = JsonUtils.stringToObject(jsonCredentials.toString(), Object.class);

ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://" + REST_HOST + ":" + REST_PORT + "/" + REST_APP + "/api/users/login",
        HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<Object>(jsonCredentialsObj, httpHeaders), User.class);
```

Where **JsonUtils.stringToObject** is my own convert utility.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's RestTemplate does not know how to serialize the Android org.json.JSONObject class. (org.json.JSONObject is not available in "normal"/desktop Java)

RestTemplate for Android supports

Jackson JSON Processor, Jackson 2.x, and Google Gson.

per: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/rest-template.html

With Jackson on the classpath RestTemplate should understand how to serialize Java beans.

```
CredentialsResource cr = new CredentialsResource();
cr.setEmail(...);
cr.setPassword(...);

HttpEntity<CredentialsResource> entityCredentials = new HttpEntity<CredentialsResource>(cr, httpHeaders);
```

P.S. It would be pretty easy to write your own JSONObjectHttpMessageConverter if you wanted to carry on using JSONObject, your converter should just have to call .toString()