# Post Json Array in Json Object via RestTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

Im trying to post an array in a json object using RestTemplate

```
{
  "update": {
    "name": "xyz",
    "id": "C2",
    "Description": "aaaaaa",
    "members": ["abc", "xyz"]
  }
}
```

Here is my PostMapping Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/update")
public Update update(@RequestBody Update update) {
    String url = "";
    HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders("username", "passowrd");
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("update", update);
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Update> update = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request, Update.class);

    return update.getBody();
}
```

And this my POJO

```java
public class Update {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String Descripion;
    private List<String> members;
}
```

And Im getting 500

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-03-13T06:31:21.822+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "No HttpMessageConverter for org.json.JSONObject and content type \"application/json\""
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code how you construct the `RestTemplate` instance?

Comment: Did have a look at this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753773/could-not-write-request-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-request-type?

Comment: @Bean
  public RestTemplate getRestTemp() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }

Comment: @POOJA -- can you put the info from your comment into the question? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your RestTemplate with a Json Message Converter.

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

You may refer this blog post for a detailed explanation

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

And then perform your rest call as below.You will no longer need to explicitly create a Json Object.

```
String url = "";
HttpEntity<Update> request = new HttpEntity<>(update, headers);
ResponseEntity<Update> firewallGroupUpdate = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Update.class);
return firewallGroupUpdate.getBody();
```

Comment: so before making this change you got 500 error and after making this change you get 400 ?

Comment: Yes, now Im getting 400

Answer (score 0):

Changed resttemplate.exchange to resttemplate.postForObject.
And also changed the method to return String.

```
public String groupUpdate(@RequestBody String groupUpdate) {
        String url = "";
        HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders("username","password");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(groupUpdate, headers);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url,requestEntity,String.class);
        return response;
    }
```